# error in sql syntax mysql node js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
 { Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''mom12345'' at line 1}
```

I am trying to write a log in query in mysql using node js but for some reason,  I keep getting the above error. Kindly can anyone assist me.

```
var logininfo={
username:username,
password:password

};
con.query('SELECT id FROM userinfo WHERE username=? and password ?',logininfo, function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) {
                console.log("error ocurred",error);

            } else {
                console.log('The solution is: ', results);
                if (results.length > 0) {
                    if ([0].password == password) {
                       console.log("Login Successful");

                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("Username and password donot match");
                    }
                }
            }
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot equal to sign

```
WHERE username=? and password = ?
                           ---^
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second parameter should be an array of parameters not an object.

So change:

```
    var logininfo={
    username:username,
    password:password
    };
```

To:

```
    var logininfo=[
    username,
    password
    ];
```